# Flutter can't find file downloaded to the flutter_assets folder

Tags: flutter

I download a file from AWS after runtime, and I checked to confirm that the file gets saved correctly in:
`/data/user/0/APPNAME/app_flutter/flutter_assets/FILENAME.zip`
where APPNAME is the name of my app and FILENAME is the name of the file I store.
Then I have a function from a package that needs to access this file, but it has to be in the **flutter_assets** folder. However, I get a  `java.io.FileNotFoundException: flutter_assets/FILENAME.zip` . I tried adding flutter_assets to the  `pubspec.yaml`
file like this:

```
flutter:
   assets:
    - flutter_assets/
```

and also added this:

```
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'zip'
    }
```

to `android/app/build.gradle` within the `android{...}`  block but it didn't help.

Comment: What does `from AWS after runtime` mean exactly? You ran the App and downloaded a file, expecting it to be saved into the assets folder? Usually, `flutter_assets/` is for bundling and deploying an App and not a download location.

Comment: I start the app, then I press a button and a file is stored. I use this   
- ```final documentsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();``` to store the file. And it gets located in the **app_flutter** folder. However, a package I use can only access **flutter_assets** so I add this:  ```final filepath = documentsDir.path + '/flutter_assets/$FILENAME.zip';``` I can see the file get downloaded in the correct place using the **Device File Explorer** but when I try to access it I get the above exception.